# MySQL get highest number of column based on another columns limit?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns siteID and site_equip_id.

So siteID is a number of a place.
site_equip_id is a number that increments only based on the siteID number.  There can be duplicates, so I they would have to be removed.

for example

```
siteID    site_equip_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
3         1
3         2
```

I would like to find just the highest number base on the siteID, but the number comes from the column site_equip_id

This is what I attempted but didn't work (just gave me the highest value for only site_equip_id - not limited by the siteID):

```
SELECT MAX(site_equip_id)+1 as site_equip_id
FROM equipment
WHERE site_id = 1
```

Comment: update you question an show the excpected  result based on your sample  ..

Comment: The Group By solved the issue

Comment: i don't undestand your comment  ... please explain better .. and add a proper sample and expected  result ... what mean 700s  or 200s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need  the highest value for each siet_id you can use a grop  by

```
SELECT MAX(site_equip_id)+1 as site_equip_id
FROM equipment
group by  site_id
```

or

```
SELECT site_id, MAX(site_equip_id)+1 as site_equip_id
FROM equipment
group by  site_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that you looking for?

```
SELECT MAX(site_equip_id) as site_equip_id FROM equipment GROUP BY site_id ;
```